# How Spring Security get currently logged in user in concept?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I get the currently logged in user by 
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` in server side and do some logging on users.

Here is the question:
Suppose I have three user logged in.
How the server side can identify the user just simply calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` ?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default there are 3 important things here:

- HTTP session - stores authentication object between requests
- Servlet API filter - populates `SecurityContextHolder` before each request from HTTP session (and stores authentication object back once the request has completed)
- `ThreadLocal` - stores authentication object during request processing

After authentication corresponding `SecurityContext` object is stored in HTTP session.
Before each request processing special `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` is fired. It is responsible for loading of `SecurityContext` object from HTTP session (via `SecurityContextRepository` instance) and for injecting `SecurityContext` object into `SecurityContextHolder`. Take a look at the source code of `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` class for more details. Another important part is that by default `SecurityContextHolder` stores `SecurityContext` object using `ThreadLocal` variable (so you will have a different authentication object per thread).

**EDIT.** Additional questions:

1. *HTTP session is saved in client's browser and updated between requests.* No, HTTP session is stored in server side. It is linked to some user via session coockie (browser send this cookie during each request).
2. *SecurityContext, SecurityContextHolder and SecurityContextRepository are instances in Server side.* They are used on server side. But `SecurityContextHolder` is not an instance, it is a helper class with static methods.
3. *ThreadLocal is a variable storing SecurityContextHolder which stores SecurityContext* No, `SecurityContext` is stored in `ThreadLocal` variable. `SecurityContextHolder` is a helper class that may be used to get/set `SecurityContext` instance via `ThreadLocal` variable.
4. *If there are three connections, then there will be three SecurityContext object in Server.* Yep.
5. *One SecurityContextHolder stores one SecurityContext* No, the same static methods of `SecurityContextHolder` used by all threads to get/set **corresponding** `SecurityContext`.
6. *And suppose there are three SecurityContext instances in Server Side, how does it knows which one refers to that corresponding client?* `ThreadLocal` variable has different values for different threads.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Below are the things I want to ask or confirm:
1) HTTP session is saved in client's browser and updated between requests.
2) SecurityContext, SecurityContextHolder and SecurityContextRepository are instances in Server side.
3) ThreadLocal is a variable storing SecurityContextHolder which stores SecurityContext
4) If there are three connections, then there will be three SecurityContext object in Server.
5) One SecurityContextHolder stores one SecurityContext

Comment: And suppose there are three SecurityContext instances in Server Side, how does it knows which one refers to that corresponding client?

Comment: My responses are in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For every `logged-in` user, there will be different sessions. Every `session` have its own configuration. Therefore, at *server side*, `SecurityContext` load data specific to a `session`. You can visualise data in `SecurityContext` as a `map`(key-value) pair.